# удалить сессию когда пользователь перешел на другую страничку

Tags: php, сессия

Я храню ошибки при регистрации/входе в сессии, и мне надо, чтобы когда пользователь ушел на другую страницу, чтобы сессия удалилась

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удаление сессии:https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-destroy.php

Создаём destroy.php:

```
//Очищаем сессию.
$_SESSION = array();

// Если требуется уничтожить сессию, также необходимо удалить сессионные cookie.
// Это уничтожит сессию, а не только её данные!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

session_destroy();
```

У клиента:

```
window.addEventListener("unload", function() {
  navigator.sendBeacon("/destroy.php","");
});
```

Comment: спасибо, сработало :)*

Answer (score 0):

```
// destroy session:
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();

//Но вам же, наверное, не всю сессию, а только ошибки? тогда как-то так:
$_SESSION['errors'] = null;
```